# How to get relations from another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to copy the relations of a class A to a class B

```
class ShoppingList
  has_many :ingredients
end

class Recipe
  has_many :ingredients
end
```

I want to add the ingredients of a recipe to a shopping list, but FROM the recipe page (I won't elaborate why but it makes sense in the UX). Ingredients are the only relation they have in common.

The logic is : On my recipe page, I wish to have a drop-down menu containing my shopping lists. Then, when I select a shopping list and validate, it will add the ingredients of the recipe to the shopping list.

I've been struggling to make this work, I know there's possibly multiple things I did wrong, but here's what I tried :

recipes_controller.rb :

```
def add_ingredients_to_list
  # call method to find the @recipe
  tmp = ShoppingList.find_by_id(shopping_list_params[:shopping_lists])
  tmp.ingredients << @recipe.ingredients
  redirect_to shopping_list_path(id: tmp.id)
end

private

def shopping_list_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:shopping_lists, :id)
end
```

routes.rb :

```
resources :recipes do
  post 'add_ingredients_to_list' => "recipes#add_ingredients_to_list"
end
```

recipes/show.html.erb :

```
<%= simple_form_for :recipe, :url => recipe_add_ingredients_to_list_url(@recipe), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :id, :input_html => { :value => @recipe.id}, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :shopping_lists, collecton: ShoppingList.all, as: :select %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

With this code, I'm getting this trace :

```
Rendered recipes/show.html.erb within layouts/application (122.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 395ms (ActiveRecord: 109.7ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `shopping_lists' for #<Recipe:0x000055a4c080af88>):
    54:           <% end %>
    55:           <%= simple_form_for :recipe, :url => recipe_add_ingredients_to_list_url(@recipe), :method => 'post' do |f| %>
    56:             <%= f.input :id, :input_html => { :value => @recipe.id}, as: :hidden %>
    57:             <%= f.input :shopping_lists, collecton: ShoppingList.all, as: :select %>
    58:             <%= f.button :submit %>
    59:           <% end %>
    60:         </div>

app/views/recipes/show.html.erb:57:in `block in _app_views_recipes_show_html_erb___4100323442142788090_47083061551380'
app/views/recipes/show.html.erb:55:in `_app_views_recipes_show_html_erb___4100323442142788090_47083061551380'
```

My best guess is that the simple_form is not suited for what I want to do, but I really don't know how to make this feature.

Could you help me ?

Comment: Where exactly is that error being thrown? Please add your stack trace to your question.

Comment: Is there `has_many :shopping_lists` in the Ingredient model? If you, I think you just need `has_many :shopping_lists, through: :ingredients` in the Recipe modell

Comment: Also, what does your `Ingredient` model look like? Specifically, its associations.

Comment: @jvillian : I've added the strack trace

Comment: @maxpleaner : I can access the page by adding your line in my model, but then the drop-down menu gives me only two options : "yes" or "no"